# Fedora 15 manual?

Tags: linux, fedora

Like the *Beginning Fedora: From Novice to Professional* book, I'm searching for a good book regarding [Fedora *15*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Fedora_versions#Fedora_15) (*Lovelock*)! Things sure changed from the older versions, so are there any good documentations about the newest, Fedora 15?

Comment: Has it been out long enough to write a book?

Comment: I suppose buying recommendations are considered off topic here, as well as such a subjective question (what constitutes a "good" book?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a paper book, but http://docs.fedoraproject.org/ has some manuals for Fedora 15. More to come, probably, but most of the manuals for version 14 are valid for version 15 as well.

As for what's new, look in the *Release Notes* document from the same place.